# Spring Cloud Stream connect to multiple hosts for single binder (RabbitMQ)

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

we are using Spring Cloud Stream to listen to rabbitMQ multiple queues, especially the SCF model

- The spring-cloud-stream-reactive module is deprecated in favor of native support via Spring Cloud Function programming model.

by the time there was a single node/host it was working good (application.yml snippet shared below),

however the moment we try to connect multiple nodes it is failing,
Can someone guide how to connect the same
or have some sample related to [Spring Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders)

**Following Code is working as expected**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: function1;function2;function3
      bindings:
        function1-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit
        function2-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit
        function3-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          function1-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.1
          function2-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.2
          function3-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.3
        binder:
          nodes: address1
```

**Basically it need to be something like following**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: function1;function2;function3
      bindings:
        function1-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit1
        function2-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit2
        function3-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: destinationExchange
          binder: rabbit3
      binder:
        rabbit1:
          function1-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.1
          binder:
            nodes: address1
        rabbit2:
          function2-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.2
          binder:
            nodes: address2
        rabbit3:
          function3-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.3
          binder:
            nodes: address3
```

with following addition itself

```
binders:
    rabbit1:
      type: rabbit
      environment:
        spring.spring.cloud.stream.kafka:
          binder:
            nodes: localhost
```

i am getting this error

```
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown binder configuration: rabbit
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.gap.pem.Application.main(Application.java:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown binder configuration: rabbit
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:255) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:224) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:386) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindConsumer(BindingService.java:103) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindInputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(InputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.InputBindingLifecycle.start(InputBindingLifecycle.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 14 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

we have following dependencies available

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit'
```

Comment: Can you update the questions with error/stacktrace ?

Comment: @SANN3 Thanks for pointing out , i have updated logs and more details

Comment: there was a typo from my side 
instead of having binder: rabbit1/rabbit2/rabbit3
i had put binder:rabbit for one of the consumer 
post that it got resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon adding the binders config for both rabbit1 and rabbit2 it resolved the issue:

Below is the sample config which I tried and was able to consume messages successfully

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processFirstConsumer;processSecondConsumer
      bindings:
        processFirstConsumer-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: userMessage1
          binder: rabbit1
        processSecondConsumer-in-0:
          group: allocation
          destination: userMessage2
          binder: rabbit2
      binder:
        rabbit1:
          processFirstConsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.1
          binder:
            nodes: address1
        rabbit2:
          processSecondConsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: routing.key.2
          binder:
            nodes: address2
      binders:
        rabbit1:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
                virtual-host: /
        rabbit2:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
                virtual-host: /
```

Comment: Are the Routing Keys working for you? I have the exact same setup dan everything beneath "binder:" is ignored.

Comment: For me this only worked partially. Routing Keys with multiple RabbitMQs are not configured under `spring.cloud.stream.binder.......` but under `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.....` It is the same as when only one Rabbit is configured. *In Spring boot 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot getting this to run. Especially with routing keys. In the end my solution was a bitt different than shown here. In hopes that it will help someone in the future :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        rabbit1:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                addresses: some.server.com:5672,some.other.server.com:5672
                username: someUserName
                password: someUserPassword
        rabbit2:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                addresses: some.rabbit2.server.us:5672,someother.rabbit2.server.de:5672
                username: secondRabbitUserName
                password: secondRabbitPassword
      function:
        definition: someReceiver;anotherRec
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          someReceiver-in-0:
            consumer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              republishToDlq: true
              bindingRoutingKey: some.routing.key.#
          anotherRec-in-0:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: finished.#
          firstAction-out-0:
            producer:
              routingKeyExpression: "'switch.'+headers.someValue+'.'+headers.someOtherValue"
              bindingRoutingKey: switch.#
          userNotification-out-0:
            producer:
              routingKeyExpression: "'switch.someKeyExpression'"
              bindingRoutingKey: switch.#
      bindings:
        anotherRec-in-0:
          destination: reciving.exchange.name
          group: some-queue-name-v7
          binder: rabbit1
        firstAction-out-0:
          destination: some.exhange.name.1
          binder: rabbit1
        someReceiver-in-0:
          destination: another.exchange.name.1
          group: queueName
          binder: rabbit2
        userNotification-out-0:
          destination: the.exchange.name
          binder: rabbit2
```