# Spring Cloud Stream connect to multiple hosts for single binder (Kafka)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

what would it look like for kafka binder
similar to - [Spring Cloud Stream connect to multiple hosts for single binder (RabbitMQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216982/spring-cloud-stream-connect-to-multiple-hosts-for-single-binder-rabbitmq)

my yaml  is like
binders:
kafka1:
type: stream
default-candidate: false
environment:
brokers:

If I give in binding it gives error in intellij, Kafka1  cannot be resolved

```
  bindings:
    input-in-0:
      destination: topic1
      group: grp1
      binder: kafka1
```

Comment: You might want to refer to here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-systems

Comment: Thanks Sobychacko , are we saying spring cloud kstream is now supporting multi cluster for kafka binder. I mean different topic can be configured with different brokers eg in-topic1 - broker1, and out-topic to broker list 2. Appreciate if you can help me with spring cloud compatible version for kafka

Comment: For Kafka Streams, multi cluster is not supported. But if you are using the regular message channel based binder, it is supported.

Comment: Sure Thank you so much Sobychacko